# 'QPixmap' has no attribute 'grabWindow'

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying convert my code from PyQt4 to PyQt5 but I am getting errors.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.now()
filename = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.jpg')
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QPixmap.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId()).save(filename, 'jpg')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Projects\name.py", line 9, in <module>
    QPixmap.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId()).save(filename, 'jpg')
AttributeError: type object 'QPixmap' has no attribute 'grabWindow'
```

Comment: I will do it now. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `QScreen::grabWindow()` instead. `QPixmap::grabWindow()` [is deprecated in Qt 5.0 because](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap-obsolete.html#grabWindow):

> there might be platform plugins in which window system identifiers (WId) are local to a screen.

Answer (score 1):

`grabWindow` method is now available in `QScreen` class.

You need to create `QScreen` object, initialize it with ex. `QtGuiApplication.primaryScreen()` and then grab the screen

```
screen.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId())
```

Answer (score 0):

Full example for **PyQt5**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QScreen
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.now()
filename = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.jpg')
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QScreen.grabWindow(app.primaryScreen(), 
QApplication.desktop().winId()).save(filename, 'png')
```