# Is it possible to drag a QTabWidget and open a new window containing what's in this Tab in pyqt5?

Tags: python, tabs, pyqt, window

I'm wondering if it is possible by clicking and dragging a Tab to open a new window with what was in that Tab. If it's possible, I would like to also do the reverse: dragging the new window inside the Tabs (where it was in the first place).

I don't know how should I start. I read in some forums that all must be coded but I don't know if Qt allows some facilities to do that?

Here a code as a starting point:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class SurfViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SurfViewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent 
        self.centralTabs= QTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralTabs)
        self.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.setFixedHeight(200)

        #tab 1 
        self.tab_1 = QWidget()
        self.centralTabs.addTab(self.tab_1,"Label") 
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        Label = QLabel('Tab1')
        Label.setFixedWidth(180)
        LineEdit = QLineEdit('Tab1')
        LineEdit.setFixedWidth(180)
        vbox.addWidget(Label)
        vbox.addWidget(LineEdit)
        vbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.tab_1.setLayout(vbox)

        #tab 2 
        self.tab_2 = QWidget()
        self.centralTabs.addTab(self.tab_2,"Label")
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        Label = QLabel('Tab2')
        Label.setFixedWidth(180)
        LineEdit = QLineEdit('Tab2')
        LineEdit.setFixedWidth(180)
        vbox.addWidget(Label)
        vbox.addWidget(LineEdit)
        vbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.tab_2.setLayout(vbox)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SurfViewer(app)
    ex.setWindowTitle('window') 
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_( ))
```

This is far from my Qt level, so I'm asking some help.
If I well understood, I need to reimplement the `mousePressEvent()` and  the `dragMoveEvent()` of the `QTabWidget`?
Their is this topic: [In PyQt4, is it possible to detach tabs from a QTabWidget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47267195/in-pyqt4-is-it-possible-to-detach-tabs-from-a-qtabwidget) but it is with PYQT4 and I'm using PYQT5.

### update

So, according to [In PyQt4, is it possible to detach tabs from a QTabWidget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47267195/in-pyqt4-is-it-possible-to-detach-tabs-from-a-qtabwidget) and after conversion toward pyqt5

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class DetachableTabWidget(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QTabWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.tabBar = self.TabBar(self)
        self.tabBar.onDetachTabSignal.connect(self.detachTab)
        self.tabBar.onMoveTabSignal.connect(self.moveTab)

        self.setTabBar(self.tabBar)


    ##
    #  The default movable functionality of QTabWidget must remain disabled
    #  so as not to conflict with the added features
    def setMovable(self, movable):
        pass

    ##
    #  Move a tab from one position (index) to another
    #
    #  @param    fromIndex    the original index location of the tab
    #  @param    toIndex      the new index location of the tab
    @pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def moveTab(self, fromIndex, toIndex):
        widget = self.widget(fromIndex)
        icon = self.tabIcon(fromIndex)
        text = self.tabText(fromIndex)

        self.removeTab(fromIndex)
        self.insertTab(toIndex, widget, icon, text)
        self.setCurrentIndex(toIndex)


    ##
    #  Detach the tab by removing it's contents and placing them in
    #  a DetachedTab dialog
    #
    #  @param    index    the index location of the tab to be detached
    #  @param    point    the screen position for creating the new DetachedTab dialog
    @pyqtSlot(int, QPoint)
    def detachTab(self, index, point):

        # Get the tab content
        name = self.tabText(index)
        icon = self.tabIcon(index)        
        if icon.isNull():
            icon = self.window().windowIcon()              
        contentWidget = self.widget(index)
        contentWidgetRect = contentWidget.frameGeometry()

        # Create a new detached tab window
        detachedTab = self.DetachedTab(contentWidget, self.parentWidget())
        detachedTab.setWindowModality(Qt.NonModal)
        detachedTab.setWindowTitle(name)
        detachedTab.setWindowIcon(icon)
        detachedTab.setObjectName(name)
        detachedTab.setGeometry(contentWidgetRect)
        detachedTab.onCloseSignal.connect(self.attachTab)
        detachedTab.move(point)
        detachedTab.show()


    ##
    #  Re-attach the tab by removing the content from the DetachedTab dialog,
    #  closing it, and placing the content back into the DetachableTabWidget
    #
    #  @param    contentWidget    the content widget from the DetachedTab dialog
    #  @param    name             the name of the detached tab
    #  @param    icon             the window icon for the detached tab
    @pyqtSlot(QWidget, type(''), QIcon)
    def attachTab(self, contentWidget, name, icon):

        # Make the content widget a child of this widget
        contentWidget.setParent(self)


        # Create an image from the given icon
        if not icon.isNull():
            tabIconPixmap = icon.pixmap(icon.availableSizes()[0])
            tabIconImage = tabIconPixmap.toImage()
        else:
            tabIconImage = None


        # Create an image of the main window icon
        if not icon.isNull():
            windowIconPixmap = self.window().windowIcon().pixmap(icon.availableSizes()[0])
            windowIconImage = windowIconPixmap.toImage()
        else:
            windowIconImage = None


        # Determine if the given image and the main window icon are the same.
        # If they are, then do not add the icon to the tab
        if tabIconImage == windowIconImage:
            index = self.addTab(contentWidget, name)
        else:
            index = self.addTab(contentWidget, icon, name)


        # Make this tab the current tab
        if index > -1:
            self.setCurrentIndex(index)


    ##
    #  When a tab is detached, the contents are placed into this QDialog.  The tab
    #  can be re-attached by closing the dialog or by double clicking on its
    #  window frame.
    class DetachedTab(QDialog):
        onCloseSignal = pyqtSignal(QWidget,type(''), QIcon)

        def __init__(self, contentWidget, parent=None):
            QDialog.__init__(self, parent)

            layout = QVBoxLayout(self)            
            self.contentWidget = contentWidget            
            layout.addWidget(self.contentWidget)
            self.contentWidget.show()
            self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window)


        ##
        #  Capture a double click event on the dialog's window frame
        #
        #  @param    event    an event
        #
        #  @return            true if the event was recognized
        def event(self, event):

            # If the event type is QEvent.NonClientAreaMouseButtonDblClick then
            # close the dialog
            if event.type() == 176:
                event.accept()
                self.close()

            return QDialog.event(self, event)


        ##
        #  If the dialog is closed, emit the onCloseSignal and give the
        #  content widget back to the DetachableTabWidget
        #
        #  @param    event    a close event
        def closeEvent(self, event):
            self.onCloseSignal.emit(self.contentWidget, self.objectName(), self.windowIcon())


    ##
    #  The TabBar class re-implements some of the functionality of the QTabBar widget
    class TabBar(QTabBar):
        onDetachTabSignal = pyqtSignal(int, QPoint)
        onMoveTabSignal = pyqtSignal(int, int)

        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QTabBar.__init__(self, parent)

            self.setAcceptDrops(True)
            self.setElideMode(Qt.ElideRight)
            self.setSelectionBehaviorOnRemove(QTabBar.SelectLeftTab)

            self.dragStartPos = QPoint()
            self.dragDropedPos = QPoint()
            self.mouseCursor = QCursor()
            self.dragInitiated = False


        ##
        #  Send the onDetachTabSignal when a tab is double clicked
        #
        #  @param    event    a mouse double click event
        def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
            event.accept()
            self.onDetachTabSignal.emit(self.tabAt(event.pos()), self.mouseCursor.pos())


        ##
        #  Set the starting position for a drag event when the mouse button is pressed
        #
        #  @param    event    a mouse press event
        def mousePressEvent(self, event):
            if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
                self.dragStartPos = event.pos()

            self.dragDropedPos.setX(0)
            self.dragDropedPos.setY(0)

            self.dragInitiated = False

            QTabBar.mousePressEvent(self, event)


        ##
        #  Determine if the current movement is a drag.  If it is, convert it into a QDrag.  If the
        #  drag ends inside the tab bar, emit an onMoveTabSignal.  If the drag ends outside the tab
        #  bar, emit an onDetachTabSignal.
        #
        #  @param    event    a mouse move event
        def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):

            # Determine if the current movement is detected as a drag
            if not self.dragStartPos.isNull() and ((event.pos() - self.dragStartPos).manhattanLength() < QApplication.startDragDistance()):
                self.dragInitiated = True

            # If the current movement is a drag initiated by the left button
            if (((event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton)) and self.dragInitiated):

                # Stop the move event
                finishMoveEvent = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseMove, event.pos(), Qt.NoButton, Qt.NoButton, Qt.NoModifier)
                QTabBar.mouseMoveEvent(self, finishMoveEvent)

                # Convert the move event into a drag
                drag = QDrag(self)
                mimeData = QMimeData()
                mimeData.setData('action', b'application/tab-detach')
                drag.setMimeData(mimeData)

                #Create the appearance of dragging the tab content
                pixmap = self.parentWidget().grab()
                targetPixmap = QPixmap(pixmap.size())
                targetPixmap.fill(Qt.transparent)
                painter = QPainter(targetPixmap)
                painter.setOpacity(0.85)
                painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap)
                painter.end()
                drag.setPixmap(targetPixmap)

                # Initiate the drag
                dropAction = drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction | Qt.CopyAction)

                # If the drag completed outside of the tab bar, detach the tab and move
                # the content to the current cursor position
                if dropAction == Qt.IgnoreAction:
                    event.accept()
                    self.onDetachTabSignal.emit(self.tabAt(self.dragStartPos), self.mouseCursor.pos())

                # Else if the drag completed inside the tab bar, move the selected tab to the new position
                elif dropAction == Qt.MoveAction:
                    if not self.dragDropedPos.isNull():
                        event.accept()
                        self.onMoveTabSignal.emit(self.tabAt(self.dragStartPos), self.tabAt(self.dragDropedPos))
            else:
                QTabBar.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)


        ##
        #  Determine if the drag has entered a tab position from another tab position
        #
        #  @param    event    a drag enter event
        def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
            mimeData = event.mimeData()
            formats = mimeData.formats()

            if 'action' in formats and mimeData.data('action') == 'application/tab-detach':
                event.acceptProposedAction()

            QTabBar.dragMoveEvent(self, event)


        ##
        #  Get the position of the end of the drag
        #
        #  @param    event    a drop event
        def dropEvent(self, event):
            self.dragDropedPos = event.pos()
            QTabBar.dropEvent(self, event)

class SurfViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SurfViewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.centralTabs= DetachableTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralTabs)
        self.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.setFixedHeight(200)

        #tab 1
        self.tab_1 = QWidget()
        self.centralTabs.addTab(self.tab_1,"Label")
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        Label = QLabel('Tab1')
        Label.setFixedWidth(180)
        LineEdit = QLineEdit('Tab1')
        LineEdit.setFixedWidth(180)
        vbox.addWidget(Label)
        vbox.addWidget(LineEdit)
        vbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.tab_1.setLayout(vbox)

        #tab 2
        self.tab_2 = QWidget()
        self.centralTabs.addTab(self.tab_2,"Label")
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        Label = QLabel('Tab2')
        Label.setFixedWidth(180)
        LineEdit = QLineEdit('Tab2')
        LineEdit.setFixedWidth(180)
        vbox.addWidget(Label)
        vbox.addWidget(LineEdit)
        vbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.tab_2.setLayout(vbox)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SurfViewer(app)
    ex.setWindowTitle('window')
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_( ))
```

It stil have one issue with that code. When several Tabs are detatched and when I close them in the wrong order, the Tabs are going in the wrong order in the main window. I would like to have them in the same order as originally

### Update 2

So I rewrite the `attachTab`function in order to put back the Tab where they were before detachment:

```
def attachTab(self, contentWidget, name, icon):

        # Make the content widget a child of this widget
        contentWidget.setParent(self)


        # Create an image from the given icon
        if not icon.isNull():
            tabIconPixmap = icon.pixmap(icon.availableSizes()[0])
            tabIconImage = tabIconPixmap.toImage()
        else:
            tabIconImage = None


        # Create an image of the main window icon
        if not icon.isNull():
            windowIconPixmap = self.window().windowIcon().pixmap(icon.availableSizes()[0])
            windowIconImage = windowIconPixmap.toImage()
        else:
            windowIconImage = None


        # Determine if the given image and the main window icon are the same.
        # If they are, then do not add the icon to the tab
        if name  == 'Model Selection':
            index = 0
        elif name  == "Model' Parameters":
            index = 1
        elif name  == 'Stim settings':
            index = 2
        elif name  == 'Parameter evolution settings':
            index = 3
        elif name  == 'LambdaE':
            index = 4
        elif name  == 'Simulation settings':
            index = 5
        elif name  == 'LFP + PPS + Pulse Results':
            index = 6
        if tabIconImage == windowIconImage:
            index = self.insertTab(index,contentWidget, name)
            # index = self.addTab(contentWidget, name)
        else:
            # index = self.addTab(contentWidget, icon, name)
            index = self.insertTab(index,contentWidget, icon, name)



        # Make this tab the current tab
        if index > -1:
            self.setCurrentIndex(index)
```

So every Tab is insert according to the starting position, but everything is done by hand. Maybe it exists an automatic way to do that.

I also increase the drag minimal distance because it seems too short too me 
ni the `mouseMoveEvent`function :

```
if not self.dragStartPos.isNull() and ((event.pos() - self.dragStartPos).manhattanLength() > QApplication.startDragDistance()*2):
```

Ialso modify the < to > to initiate the drag only if the distance is greater than `startDragDistance()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is code developed on PyQt4 for detachable tab widget in PyQt. Hope this will help you.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot

##
# The DetachableTabWidget adds additional functionality to Qt's QTabWidget that allows it
# to detach and re-attach tabs.
#
# Additional Features:
#   Detach tabs by
#     dragging the tabs away from the tab bar
#     double clicking the tab
#   Re-attach tabs by
#     closing the detached tab's window
#     double clicking the detached tab's window frame
#
# Modified Features:
#   Re-ordering (moving) tabs by dragging was re-implemented  
#   
class DetachableTabWidget(QtGui.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QTabWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.tabBar = self.TabBar(self)
        self.tabBar.onDetachTabSignal.connect(self.detachTab)
        self.tabBar.onMoveTabSignal.connect(self.moveTab)

        self.setTabBar(self.tabBar)


    ##
    #  The default movable functionality of QTabWidget must remain disabled
    #  so as not to conflict with the added features
    def setMovable(self, movable):
        pass

    ##
    #  Move a tab from one position (index) to another
    #
    #  @param    fromIndex    the original index location of the tab
    #  @param    toIndex      the new index location of the tab
    @pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def moveTab(self, fromIndex, toIndex):
        widget = self.widget(fromIndex)
        icon = self.tabIcon(fromIndex)
        text = self.tabText(fromIndex)

        self.removeTab(fromIndex)
        self.insertTab(toIndex, widget, icon, text)
        self.setCurrentIndex(toIndex)


    ##
    #  Detach the tab by removing it's contents and placing them in
    #  a DetachedTab dialog
    #
    #  @param    index    the index location of the tab to be detached
    #  @param    point    the screen position for creating the new DetachedTab dialog
    @pyqtSlot(int, QtCore.QPoint)
    def detachTab(self, index, point):

        # Get the tab content
        name = self.tabText(index)
        icon = self.tabIcon(index)        
        if icon.isNull():
            icon = self.window().windowIcon()              
        contentWidget = self.widget(index)
        contentWidgetRect = contentWidget.frameGeometry()

        # Create a new detached tab window
        detachedTab = self.DetachedTab(contentWidget, self.parentWidget())
        detachedTab.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        detachedTab.setWindowTitle(name)
        detachedTab.setWindowIcon(icon)
        detachedTab.setObjectName(name)
        detachedTab.setGeometry(contentWidgetRect)
        detachedTab.onCloseSignal.connect(self.attachTab)
        detachedTab.move(point)
        detachedTab.show()


    ##
    #  Re-attach the tab by removing the content from the DetachedTab dialog,
    #  closing it, and placing the content back into the DetachableTabWidget
    #
    #  @param    contentWidget    the content widget from the DetachedTab dialog
    #  @param    name             the name of the detached tab
    #  @param    icon             the window icon for the detached tab
    @pyqtSlot(QtGui.QWidget, QtCore.QString, QtGui.QIcon)
    def attachTab(self, contentWidget, name, icon):

        # Make the content widget a child of this widget
        contentWidget.setParent(self)


        # Create an image from the given icon
        if not icon.isNull():
            tabIconPixmap = icon.pixmap(icon.availableSizes()[0])
            tabIconImage = tabIconPixmap.toImage()
        else:
            tabIconImage = None


        # Create an image of the main window icon
        if not icon.isNull():
            windowIconPixmap = self.window().windowIcon().pixmap(icon.availableSizes()[0])
            windowIconImage = windowIconPixmap.toImage()
        else:
            windowIconImage = None


        # Determine if the given image and the main window icon are the same.
        # If they are, then do not add the icon to the tab
        if tabIconImage == windowIconImage:
            index = self.addTab(contentWidget, name)
        else:
            index = self.addTab(contentWidget, icon, name)


        # Make this tab the current tab
        if index > -1:
            self.setCurrentIndex(index)


    ##
    #  When a tab is detached, the contents are placed into this QDialog.  The tab
    #  can be re-attached by closing the dialog or by double clicking on its
    #  window frame.
    class DetachedTab(QtGui.QDialog):
        onCloseSignal = pyqtSignal(QtGui.QWidget, QtCore.QString, QtGui.QIcon)

        def __init__(self, contentWidget, parent=None):
            QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)

            layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)            
            self.contentWidget = contentWidget            
            layout.addWidget(self.contentWidget)
            self.contentWidget.show()


        ##
        #  Capture a double click event on the dialog's window frame
        #
        #  @param    event    an event
        #
        #  @return            true if the event was recognized
        def event(self, event):

            # If the event type is QEvent.NonClientAreaMouseButtonDblClick then
            # close the dialog
            if event.type() == 176:
                event.accept()
                self.close()

            return QtGui.QDialog.event(self, event)


        ##
        #  If the dialog is closed, emit the onCloseSignal and give the
        #  content widget back to the DetachableTabWidget
        #
        #  @param    event    a close event
        def closeEvent(self, event):
            self.onCloseSignal.emit(self.contentWidget, self.objectName(), self.windowIcon())


    ##
    #  The TabBar class re-implements some of the functionality of the QTabBar widget
    class TabBar(QtGui.QTabBar):
        onDetachTabSignal = pyqtSignal(int, QtCore.QPoint)
        onMoveTabSignal = pyqtSignal(int, int)

        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtGui.QTabBar.__init__(self, parent)

            self.setAcceptDrops(True)
            self.setElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideRight)
            self.setSelectionBehaviorOnRemove(QtGui.QTabBar.SelectLeftTab)

            self.dragStartPos = QtCore.QPoint()
            self.dragDropedPos = QtCore.QPoint()
            self.mouseCursor = QtGui.QCursor()
            self.dragInitiated = False


        ##
        #  Send the onDetachTabSignal when a tab is double clicked
        #
        #  @param    event    a mouse double click event
        def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
            event.accept()
            self.onDetachTabSignal.emit(self.tabAt(event.pos()), self.mouseCursor.pos())


        ##
        #  Set the starting position for a drag event when the mouse button is pressed
        #
        #  @param    event    a mouse press event
        def mousePressEvent(self, event):
            if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                self.dragStartPos = event.pos()

            self.dragDropedPos.setX(0)
            self.dragDropedPos.setY(0)

            self.dragInitiated = False

            QtGui.QTabBar.mousePressEvent(self, event)


        ##
        #  Determine if the current movement is a drag.  If it is, convert it into a QDrag.  If the
        #  drag ends inside the tab bar, emit an onMoveTabSignal.  If the drag ends outside the tab
        #  bar, emit an onDetachTabSignal.
        #
        #  @param    event    a mouse move event
        def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):

            # Determine if the current movement is detected as a drag
            if not self.dragStartPos.isNull() and ((event.pos() - self.dragStartPos).manhattanLength() < QtGui.QApplication.startDragDistance()):
                self.dragInitiated = True

            # If the current movement is a drag initiated by the left button
            if (((event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)) and self.dragInitiated):

                # Stop the move event
                finishMoveEvent = QtGui.QMouseEvent(QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove, event.pos(), QtCore.Qt.NoButton, QtCore.Qt.NoButton, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier)
                QtGui.QTabBar.mouseMoveEvent(self, finishMoveEvent)

                # Convert the move event into a drag
                drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
                mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
                mimeData.setData('action', 'application/tab-detach')
                drag.setMimeData(mimeData)

                # Create the appearance of dragging the tab content
                pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.grabWindow(self.parentWidget().currentWidget().winId())
                targetPixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(pixmap.size())
                targetPixmap.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
                painter = QtGui.QPainter(targetPixmap)
                painter.setOpacity(0.85)
                painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap)
                painter.end()
                drag.setPixmap(targetPixmap)

                # Initiate the drag
                dropAction = drag.exec_(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction | QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)

                # If the drag completed outside of the tab bar, detach the tab and move
                # the content to the current cursor position
                if dropAction == QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAction:
                    event.accept()
                    self.onDetachTabSignal.emit(self.tabAt(self.dragStartPos), self.mouseCursor.pos())

                # Else if the drag completed inside the tab bar, move the selected tab to the new position
                elif dropAction == QtCore.Qt.MoveAction:
                    if not self.dragDropedPos.isNull():
                        event.accept()
                        self.onMoveTabSignal.emit(self.tabAt(self.dragStartPos), self.tabAt(self.dragDropedPos))
            else:
                QtGui.QTabBar.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)


        ##
        #  Determine if the drag has entered a tab position from another tab position
        #
        #  @param    event    a drag enter event
        def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
            mimeData = event.mimeData()
            formats = mimeData.formats()

            if formats.contains('action') and mimeData.data('action') == 'application/tab-detach':
                event.acceptProposedAction()

            QtGui.QTabBar.dragMoveEvent(self, event)


        ##
        #  Get the position of the end of the drag
        #
        #  @param    event    a drop event
        def dropEvent(self, event):
            self.dragDropedPos = event.pos()
            QtGui.QTabBar.dropEvent(self, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    tabWidget = DetachableTabWidget(mainWindow)

    tab1 = QtGui.QLabel('Test Widget 1')    
    tabWidget.addTab(tab1, 'Tab1')

    tab2 = QtGui.QLabel('Test Widget 2')
    tabWidget.addTab(tab2, 'Tab2')

    tab3 = QtGui.QLabel('Test Widget 3')
    tabWidget.addTab(tab3, 'Tab3')

    tabWidget.show()
    mainWindow.setCentralWidget(tabWidget)
    mainWindow.show()

    try:
        exitStatus = app.exec_()
        print 'Done...'
        sys.exit(exitStatus)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: As mention in the topic, this is for pyqt4 and I'm coding with pyqt5. I don't know how convert this. Especially the QString that doesn't exist anymore

Comment: There is not much that need to do to modify code developed into PyQt4 and PyQt5. Just modify the import statement as : from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore and from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot , I hope this should work. I also work on PyQt4, and I did some simple modification when I found some PyQt5 code, thats works for me atleast.

Comment: Ok, I modify ` @pyqtSlot(QtGui.QWidget, QtCore.QString, QtGui.QIcon)` with `@pyqtSlot(QWidget, type(''), QIcon)`, `onCloseSignal = pyqtSignal(QtGui.QWidget, QtCore.QString, QtGui.QIcon)` with `onCloseSignal = pyqtSignal(QWidget,type(''), QIcon)`, `mimeData.setData('action', 'application/tab-detach')` with `mimeData.setData('action', b'application/tab-detach')`, and `if formats.contains('action')` with `if 'action' in formats`

Comment: `pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.grabWindow(self.parentWidget().currentWidget().winId())`doesn't work anymore I don't know what should I use here. I should use QScreen.grabWindow but I don't know what put as argument?

Comment: grabWindow() is depreciated in Qt5 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260686/qpixmap-has-no-attribute-grabwindow this link might help you. grabWindow() takes window id as in input. in the ans this is giving an Id : self.parentWidget().currentWidget().winId()

Comment: Ok, I converted the code, Now it works with pyqt5. However when I close the Tabs in the wrong order, the order is changed in the main window. How can I correct that?

Comment: Yes that I have also notice.. so you have to dig-out it... I think on close event you can do something. Cheers...

Answer (score 2):

### Working version for Pyside2

The [original solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47267195/in-pyqt-is-it-possible-to-detach-tabs-from-a-qtabwidget) is by user [Blackwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5622106/blackwood). All credit belongs to him! Thanks!
All I did was porting it to PySide2 (for 3ds Max CG pipeline tools and my own project manager tool)

Fixed/Added features:

- The drag & drop of the detached tab back into the tab widget was broken
- as well as the re-attachment at the previous index, to keep the original tab order.

I hope this helps anybody!
Feedback appreciated!

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PySide2.QtCore import Signal, Slot

##
# The DetachableTabWidget adds additional functionality to Qt's QTabWidget that allows it
# to detach and re-attach tabs.
#
# Additional Features:
#   Detach tabs by
#     dragging the tabs outside from the tab bar
#   Re-attach tabs by
#     dragging the detached tab's window into the tab bar
#     closing the detached tab's window (previous index preserved)
#   Remove tab (attached or detached) by name
#
# Modified Features:
#   Re-ordering (moving) tabs by dragging was re-implemented (and bugfixed)
#
#   Original by Stack Overflow user: Blackwood, 13/11/2017
#   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47267195/in-pyqt-is-it-possible-to-detach-tabs-from-a-qtabwidget
#
#   Adapted for PySide2 and bugfixed by pixhellmann, mld digits gmbh 13/07/2022
#
class DetachableTabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super().__init__()

        self.tabBar = self.TabBar(self)
        self.tabBar.onDetachTabSignal.connect(self.detachTab)
        self.tabBar.onMoveTabSignal.connect(self.moveTab)
        self.tabBar.detachedTabDropSignal.connect(self.detachedTabDrop)

        self.setTabBar(self.tabBar)

        # Used to keep a reference to detached tabs since their QMainWindow
        # does not have a parent
        self.detachedTabs = {}

        # Close all detached tabs if the application is closed explicitly
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().aboutToQuit.connect(self.closeDetachedTabs)

    ##
    #  The default movable functionality of QTabWidget must remain disabled
    #  so as not to conflict with the added features
    def setMovable(self, movable):
        pass

    ##
    #  Move a tab from one position (index) to another
    #
    #  @param    fromIndex    the original index location of the tab
    #  @param    toIndex      the new index location of the tab
    @Slot(int, int)
    def moveTab(self, fromIndex, toIndex):
        widget = self.widget(fromIndex)
        icon = self.tabIcon(fromIndex)
        text = self.tabText(fromIndex)

        self.removeTab(fromIndex)
        self.insertTab(toIndex, widget, icon, text)
        self.setCurrentIndex(toIndex)

    ##
    #  Detach the tab by removing it's contents and placing them in
    #  a DetachedTab window
    #
    #  @param    index    the index location of the tab to be detached
    #  @param    point    the screen position for creating the new DetachedTab window
    @Slot(int, QtCore.QPoint)
    def detachTab(self, index, point):

        # Get the tab content
        name = self.tabText(index)
        icon = self.tabIcon(index)
        if icon.isNull():
            icon = self.window().windowIcon()
        contentWidget = self.widget(index)

        try:
            contentWidgetRect = contentWidget.frameGeometry()
        except AttributeError:
            return

        # Create a new detached tab window
        detachedTab = self.DetachedTab(name, contentWidget, index)
        detachedTab.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        detachedTab.setWindowIcon(icon)
        detachedTab.setGeometry(contentWidgetRect)
        detachedTab.onCloseSignal.connect(self.attachTab)
        detachedTab.onDropSignal.connect(self.tabBar.detachedTabDrop)
        detachedTab.move(point)
        detachedTab.show()

        # Create a reference to maintain access to the detached tab
        self.detachedTabs[name] = detachedTab

    ##
    #  Re-attach the tab by removing the content from the DetachedTab window,
    #  closing it, and placing the content back into the DetachableTabWidget
    #
    #  @param    contentWidget    the content widget from the DetachedTab window
    #  @param    name             the name of the detached tab
    #  @param    icon             the window icon for the detached tab
    #  @param    insertAt         insert the re-attached tab at the given index
    def attachTab(self, contentWidget, name, icon, insertAt=None):

        # Make the content widget a child of this widget
        contentWidget.setParent(self)

        # Remove the reference
        del self.detachedTabs[name]

        # Create an image from the given icon (for comparison)
        if not icon.isNull():
            try:
                tabIconPixmap = icon.pixmap(icon.availableSizes()[0])
                tabIconImage = tabIconPixmap.toImage()
            except IndexError:
                tabIconImage = None
        else:
            tabIconImage = None

        # Create an image of the main window icon (for comparison)
        if not icon.isNull():
            try:
                windowIconPixmap = self.window().windowIcon().pixmap(icon.availableSizes()[0])
                windowIconImage = windowIconPixmap.toImage()
            except IndexError:
                windowIconImage = None
        else:
            windowIconImage = None

        # Determine if the given image and the main window icon are the same.
        # If they are, then do not add the icon to the tab
        if tabIconImage == windowIconImage:
            if insertAt == None:
                index = self.addTab(contentWidget, name)
            else:
                index = self.insertTab(insertAt, contentWidget, name)
        else:
            if insertAt == None:
                index = self.addTab(contentWidget, icon, name)
            else:
                index = self.insertTab(insertAt, contentWidget, icon, name)

        # Make this tab the current tab
        if index > -1:
            self.setCurrentIndex(index)

    ##
    #  Remove the tab with the given name, even if it is detached
    #
    #  @param    name    the name of the tab to be removed
    def removeTabByName(self, name):

        # Remove the tab if it is attached
        attached = False
        for index in range(self.count()):
            if str(name) == str(self.tabText(index)):
                self.removeTab(index)
                attached = True
                break

        # If the tab is not attached, close it's window and
        # remove the reference to it
        if not attached:
            for key in self.detachedTabs:
                if str(name) == str(key):
                    self.detachedTabs[key].onCloseSignal.disconnect()
                    self.detachedTabs[key].close()
                    del self.detachedTabs[key]
                    break

    ##
    #  Handle dropping of a detached tab inside the DetachableTabWidget
    #
    #  @param    name     the name of the detached tab
    #  @param    index    the index of an existing tab (if the tab bar
    #                     determined that the drop occurred on an
    #                     existing tab)
    #  @param    dropPos  the mouse cursor position when the drop occurred
    @Slot(str, int, QtCore.QPoint)
    def detachedTabDrop(self, name, index, dropPos):
        # If the drop occurred on an existing tab, insert the detached
        # tab at the existing tab's location
        if index > -1:

            # Create references to the detached tab's content and icon
            contentWidget = self.detachedTabs[name].contentWidget
            icon = self.detachedTabs[name].windowIcon()

            # Disconnect the detached tab's onCloseSignal so that it
            # does not try to re-attach automatically
            self.detachedTabs[name].onCloseSignal.disconnect()

            # Close the detached
            self.detachedTabs[name].close()

            # Re-attach the tab at the given index
            self.attachTab(contentWidget, name, icon, index)

        # If the drop did not occur on an existing tab, determine if the drop
        # occurred in the tab bar area (the area to the side of the QTabBar)
        else:

            # Find the drop position relative to the DetachableTabWidget
            tabDropPos = self.mapFromGlobal(dropPos)

            # If the drop position is inside the DetachableTabWidget...
            if self.rect().contains(tabDropPos):

                # If the drop position is inside the tab bar area (the
                # area to the side of the QTabBar) or there are not tabs
                # currently attached...
                if tabDropPos.y() < self.tabBar.height() or self.count() == 0:

                    # Close the detached tab and allow it to re-attach
                    # automatically
                    self.detachedTabs[name].close()

    ##
    #  Close all tabs that are currently detached.
    def closeDetachedTabs(self):
        listOfDetachedTabs = []
        for key in self.detachedTabs:
            listOfDetachedTabs.append(self.detachedTabs[key])

        for detachedTab in listOfDetachedTabs:
            detachedTab.close()

    ##
    #  When a tab is detached, the contents are placed into this QMainWindow.  The tab
    #  can be re-attached by closing the dialog or by dragging the window into the tab bar
    class DetachedTab(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
        onCloseSignal = Signal(QtWidgets.QWidget, str, QtGui.QIcon, int)
        onDropSignal = Signal(str, QtCore.QPoint)

        def __init__(self, name, contentWidget, index):
            QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, None)
            self.index = index
            self.setObjectName(name)
            self.setWindowTitle(name)

            self.contentWidget = contentWidget
            self.setCentralWidget(self.contentWidget)
            self.contentWidget.show()

            self.windowDropFilter = self.WindowDropFilter()
            self.installEventFilter(self.windowDropFilter)
            self.windowDropFilter.onDropSignal.connect(self.windowDropSlot)

        ##
        #  Handle a window drop event
        #
        #  @param    dropPos    the mouse cursor position of the drop
        @Slot(QtCore.QPoint)
        def windowDropSlot(self, dropPos):
            self.onDropSignal.emit(self.objectName(), dropPos)

        ##
        #  If the window is closed, emit the onCloseSignal and give the
        #  content widget back to the DetachableTabWidget
        #
        #  @param    event    a close event
        def closeEvent(self, event):
            self.onCloseSignal.emit(
                self.contentWidget, self.objectName(), self.windowIcon(), self.index
            )

        ##
        #  An event filter class to detect a QMainWindow drop event
        class WindowDropFilter(QtCore.QObject):
            onDropSignal = Signal(QtCore.QPoint)

            def __init__(self):
                QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
                self.lastEvent = None

            ##
            #  Detect a QMainWindow drop event by looking for a NonClientAreaMouseMove (173)
            #  event that immediately follows a Move event
            #
            #  @param    obj    the object that generated the event
            #  @param    event  the current event
            def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
                # If a NonClientAreaMouseMove (173) event immediately follows a Move event...
                if self.lastEvent == QtCore.QEvent.Move and event.type() == 175:
                    # Determine the position of the mouse cursor and emit it with the
                    # onDropSignal
                    mouseCursor = QtGui.QCursor()
                    dropPos = mouseCursor.pos()
                    self.onDropSignal.emit(dropPos)
                    self.lastEvent = event.type()
                    return True

                else:
                    self.lastEvent = event.type()
                    return False

    ##
    #  The TabBar class re-implements some of the functionality of the QTabBar widget
    class TabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar):
        onDetachTabSignal = Signal(int, QtCore.QPoint)
        onMoveTabSignal = Signal(int, int)
        detachedTabDropSignal = Signal(str, int, QtCore.QPoint)

        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtWidgets.QTabBar.__init__(self, parent)

            self.setAcceptDrops(True)
            self.setElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideRight)
            self.setSelectionBehaviorOnRemove(QtWidgets.QTabBar.SelectLeftTab)

            self.dragStartPos = QtCore.QPoint()
            self.dragDropedPos = QtCore.QPoint()
            self.mouseCursor = QtGui.QCursor()
            self.dragInitiated = False

        ##
        #  Send the onDetachTabSignal when a tab is double clicked
        #
        #  @param    event    a mouse double click event
        # def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        #     event.accept()
        #     self.onDetachTabSignal.emit(self.tabAt(event.pos()), self.mouseCursor.pos())

        ##
        #  Set the starting position for a drag event when the mouse button is pressed
        #
        #  @param    event    a mouse press event
        def mousePressEvent(self, event):
            if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                self.dragStartPos = event.pos()

            self.dragDropedPos.setX(0)
            self.dragDropedPos.setY(0)

            self.dragInitiated = False

            QtWidgets.QTabBar.mousePressEvent(self, event)

        ##
        #  Determine if the current movement is a drag.  If it is, convert it into a QDrag.  If the
        #  drag ends inside the tab bar, emit an onMoveTabSignal.  If the drag ends outside the tab
        #  bar, emit an onDetachTabSignal.
        #
        #  @param    event    a mouse move event
        def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
            # Determine if the current movement is detected as a drag (when outside the tab and above the drag distance)
            if not self.dragStartPos.isNull() and (
                (event.pos() - self.dragStartPos).manhattanLength()
                > QtWidgets.QApplication.startDragDistance() + 10
            ):
                self.dragInitiated = True

            # If the current movement is a drag initiated by the left button
            if ((event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)) and self.dragInitiated:

                # Stop the move event
                finishMoveEvent = QtGui.QMouseEvent(
                    QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove,
                    event.pos(),
                    QtCore.Qt.NoButton,
                    QtCore.Qt.NoButton,
                    QtCore.Qt.NoModifier,
                )
                QtWidgets.QTabBar.mouseMoveEvent(self, finishMoveEvent)

                # Convert the move event into a drag
                drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
                mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
                mimeData.setData("action", QtCore.QByteArray(b"application/tab-detach"))
                drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
                # Create the appearance of dragging the tab content
                pixmap = self.parent().widget(self.tabAt(self.dragStartPos)).grab()
                targetPixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(pixmap.size())
                targetPixmap.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
                painter = QtGui.QPainter(targetPixmap)
                painter.setOpacity(0.85)
                painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap)
                painter.end()
                drag.setPixmap(targetPixmap)

                # Initiate the drag
                dropAction = drag.exec_(
                    QtCore.Qt.CopyAction | QtCore.Qt.MoveAction, QtCore.Qt.CopyAction
                )

                # For Linux:  Here, drag.exec_() will not return MoveAction on Linux.  So it
                #             must be set manually
                if self.dragDropedPos.x() != 0 and self.dragDropedPos.y() != 0:
                    dropAction = QtCore.Qt.MoveAction

                # If the drag completed outside of the tab bar, detach the tab and move
                # the content to the current cursor position
                if dropAction == QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAction:
                    event.accept()
                    self.onDetachTabSignal.emit(
                        self.tabAt(self.dragStartPos), self.mouseCursor.pos()
                    )

                # Else if the drag completed inside the tab bar, move the selected tab to the new position
                elif dropAction == QtCore.Qt.MoveAction:
                    if not self.dragDropedPos.isNull():
                        event.accept()
                        self.onMoveTabSignal.emit(
                            self.tabAt(self.dragStartPos), self.tabAt(self.dragDropedPos)
                        )
            else:
                QtWidgets.QTabBar.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)

        ##
        #  Determine if the drag has entered a tab position from another tab position
        #
        #  @param    event    a drag enter event
        def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
            mimeData = event.mimeData()
            formats = mimeData.formats()
            # check if drag mime data contains the action that detached it, to accept the drop
            if "action" in formats and mimeData.data("action") == QtCore.QByteArray(
                b"application/tab-detach"
            ):
                event.acceptProposedAction()

            QtWidgets.QTabBar.dragMoveEvent(self, event)

        ##
        #  Get the position of the end of the drag
        #
        #  @param    event    a drop event
        def dropEvent(self, event):
            self.dragDropedPos = event.pos()
            QtWidgets.QTabBar.dropEvent(self, event)

        ##
        #  Determine if the detached tab drop event occurred on an existing tab,
        #  then send the event to the DetachableTabWidget
        def detachedTabDrop(self, name, dropPos):

            tabDropPos = self.mapFromGlobal(dropPos)

            index = self.tabAt(tabDropPos)

            self.detachedTabDropSignal.emit(name, index, dropPos)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    tabWidget = DetachableTabWidget()

    tab1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Test Widget 1")
    tabWidget.addTab(tab1, "Tab1")

    tab2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Test Widget 2")
    tabWidget.addTab(tab2, "Tab2")

    tab3 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Test Widget 3")
    tabWidget.addTab(tab3, "Tab3")

    tabWidget.show()
    mainWindow.setCentralWidget(tabWidget)
    mainWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely right. Just added them. Better like this?

Answer (score 1):

## Working version for PyQt 6

Here is a modified version of the code posted by @ymmx, working on PyQt6.

```
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class DetachableTabWidget(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QTabWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.tabBar = self.TabBar(self)
        self.tabBar.onDetachTabSignal.connect(self.detachTab)
        self.tabBar.onMoveTabSignal.connect(self.moveTab)

        self.setTabBar(self.tabBar)


    ##
    #  The default movable functionality of QTabWidget must remain disabled
    #  so as not to conflict with the added features
    def setMovable(self, movable):
        pass

    ##
    #  Move a tab from one position (index) to another
    #
    #  @param    fromIndex    the original index location of the tab
    #  @param    toIndex      the new index location of the tab
    @pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def moveTab(self, fromIndex, toIndex):
        widget = self.widget(fromIndex)
        icon = self.tabIcon(fromIndex)
        text = self.tabText(fromIndex)

        self.removeTab(fromIndex)
        self.insertTab(toIndex, widget, icon, text)
        self.setCurrentIndex(toIndex)


    ##
    #  Detach the tab by removing it's contents and placing them in
    #  a DetachedTab dialog
    #
    #  @param    index    the index location of the tab to be detached
    #  @param    point    the screen position for creating the new DetachedTab dialog
    @pyqtSlot(int, QPoint)
    def detachTab(self, index, point):

        # Get the tab content
        name = self.tabText(index)
        icon = self.tabIcon(index)        
        if icon.isNull():
            icon = self.window().windowIcon()              
        contentWidget = self.widget(index)
        contentWidgetRect = contentWidget.frameGeometry()

        # Create a new detached tab window
        detachedTab = self.DetachedTab(contentWidget, self.parentWidget())
        detachedTab.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModality.NonModal)
        detachedTab.setWindowTitle(name)
        detachedTab.setWindowIcon(icon)
        detachedTab.setObjectName(name)
        detachedTab.setGeometry(contentWidgetRect)
        detachedTab.onCloseSignal.connect(self.attachTab)
        detachedTab.move(point)
        detachedTab.show()


    ##
    #  Re-attach the tab by removing the content from the DetachedTab dialog,
    #  closing it, and placing the content back into the DetachableTabWidget
    #
    #  @param    contentWidget    the content widget from the DetachedTab dialog
    #  @param    name             the name of the detached tab
    #  @param    icon             the window icon for the detached tab
    @pyqtSlot(QWidget, type(''), QIcon)
    def attachTab(self, contentWidget, name, icon):

        # Make the content widget a child of this widget
        contentWidget.setParent(self)


        # Create an image from the given icon
        if not icon.isNull():
            tabIconPixmap = icon.pixmap(icon.availableSizes()[0])
            tabIconImage = tabIconPixmap.toImage()
        else:
            tabIconImage = None


        # Create an image of the main window icon
        if not icon.isNull():
            windowIconPixmap = self.window().windowIcon().pixmap(icon.availableSizes()[0])
            windowIconImage = windowIconPixmap.toImage()
        else:
            windowIconImage = None


        # Determine if the given image and the main window icon are the same.
        # If they are, then do not add the icon to the tab
        if name  == 'Model Selection':
            index = 0
        elif name  == "Model' Parameters":
            index = 1
        elif name  == 'Stim settings':
            index = 2
        elif name  == 'Parameter evolution settings':
            index = 3
        elif name  == 'LambdaE':
            index = 4
        elif name  == 'Simulation settings':
            index = 5
        elif name  == 'LFP + PPS + Pulse Results':
            index = 6
        else:
            index = 7
        if tabIconImage == windowIconImage:
            index = self.insertTab(index,contentWidget, name)
            # index = self.addTab(contentWidget, name)
        else:
            # index = self.addTab(contentWidget, icon, name)
            index = self.insertTab(index,contentWidget, icon, name)


        # Make this tab the current tab
        if index > -1:
            self.setCurrentIndex(index)


    ##
    #  When a tab is detached, the contents are placed into this QDialog.  The tab
    #  can be re-attached by closing the dialog or by double clicking on its
    #  window frame.
    class DetachedTab(QDialog):
        onCloseSignal = pyqtSignal(QWidget,type(''), QIcon)

        def __init__(self, contentWidget, parent=None):
            QDialog.__init__(self, parent)

            layout = QVBoxLayout(self)            
            self.contentWidget = contentWidget            
            layout.addWidget(self.contentWidget)
            self.contentWidget.show()
            self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowType.Window)


        ##
        #  Capture a double click event on the dialog's window frame
        #
        #  @param    event    an event
        #
        #  @return            true if the event was recognized
        def event(self, event):

            # If the event type is QEvent.NonClientAreaMouseButtonDblClick then
            # close the dialog
            if event.type() == 176:
                event.accept()
                self.close()

            return QDialog.event(self, event)


        ##
        #  If the dialog is closed, emit the onCloseSignal and give the
        #  content widget back to the DetachableTabWidget
        #
        #  @param    event    a close event
        def closeEvent(self, event):
            self.onCloseSignal.emit(self.contentWidget, self.objectName(), self.windowIcon())


    ##
    #  The TabBar class re-implements some of the functionality of the QTabBar widget
    class TabBar(QTabBar):
        onDetachTabSignal = pyqtSignal(int, QPoint)
        onMoveTabSignal = pyqtSignal(int, int)

        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QTabBar.__init__(self, parent)

            self.setAcceptDrops(True)
            self.setElideMode(Qt.TextElideMode.ElideRight)
            self.setSelectionBehaviorOnRemove(QTabBar.SelectionBehavior.SelectLeftTab)

            self.dragStartPos = QPoint()
            self.dragDropedPos = QPoint()
            self.mouseCursor = QCursor()
            self.dragInitiated = False


        ##
        #  Send the onDetachTabSignal when a tab is double clicked
        #
        #  @param    event    a mouse double click event
        def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
            event.accept()
            self.onDetachTabSignal.emit(self.tabAt(event.pos()), self.mouseCursor.pos())


        ##
        #  Set the starting position for a drag event when the mouse button is pressed
        #
        #  @param    event    a mouse press event
        def mousePressEvent(self, event):
            if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
                self.dragStartPos = event.pos()

            self.dragDropedPos.setX(0)
            self.dragDropedPos.setY(0)

            self.dragInitiated = False

            QTabBar.mousePressEvent(self, event)


        ##
        #  Determine if the current movement is a drag.  If it is, convert it into a QDrag.  If the
        #  drag ends inside the tab bar, emit an onMoveTabSignal.  If the drag ends outside the tab
        #  bar, emit an onDetachTabSignal.
        #
        #  @param    event    a mouse move event
        def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):

            # Determine if the current movement is detected as a drag
            # Edit : change : < to : >
            if not self.dragStartPos.isNull() and ((event.pos() - self.dragStartPos).manhattanLength() > QApplication.startDragDistance()):
                self.dragInitiated = True

            # If the current movement is a drag initiated by the left button
            if (((event.buttons() & Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton)) and self.dragInitiated):

                # Stop the move event
                finishMoveEvent = QMouseEvent(QEvent.Type.MouseMove, event.position(), Qt.MouseButton.NoButton, Qt.MouseButton.NoButton, Qt.KeyboardModifier.NoModifier)
                QTabBar.mouseMoveEvent(self, finishMoveEvent)

                # Convert the move event into a drag
                drag = QDrag(self)
                mimeData = QMimeData()
                mimeData.setData('action', b'application/tab-detach')
                drag.setMimeData(mimeData)

                #Create the appearance of dragging the tab content
                pixmap = self.parentWidget().grab()
                targetPixmap = QPixmap(pixmap.size())
                targetPixmap.fill(QColor(0,0,0,0))
                painter = QPainter(targetPixmap)
                painter.setOpacity(0.85)
                painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap)
                painter.end()
                drag.setPixmap(targetPixmap)

                # Initiate the drag
                dropAction = drag.exec(Qt.DropAction.MoveAction | Qt.DropAction.CopyAction)

                # If the drag completed outside of the tab bar, detach the tab and move
                # the content to the current cursor position
                if dropAction == Qt.DropAction.IgnoreAction:
                    event.accept()
                    self.onDetachTabSignal.emit(self.tabAt(self.dragStartPos), self.mouseCursor.pos())

                # Else if the drag completed inside the tab bar, move the selected tab to the new position
                elif dropAction == Qt.DropAction.MoveAction:
                    if not self.dragDropedPos.isNull():
                        event.accept()
                        self.onMoveTabSignal.emit(self.tabAt(self.dragStartPos), self.tabAt(self.dragDropedPos))
            else:
                QTabBar.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)


        ##
        #  Determine if the drag has entered a tab position from another tab position
        #
        #  @param    event    a drag enter event
        def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
            mimeData = event.mimeData()
            formats = mimeData.formats()

            if 'action' in formats and mimeData.data('action') == 'application/tab-detach':
                event.acceptProposedAction()

            QTabBar.dragMoveEvent(self, event)


        ##
        #  Get the position of the end of the drag
        #
        #  @param    event    a drop event
        def dropEvent(self, event):
            self.dragDropedPos = event.position()
            QTabBar.dropEvent(self, event)





class SurfViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SurfViewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.centralTabs= DetachableTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralTabs)
        self.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.setFixedHeight(200)

        #tab 1
        self.tab_1 = QWidget()
        self.centralTabs.addTab(self.tab_1,"Label")
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        Label = QLabel('Tab1')
        Label.setFixedWidth(180)
        LineEdit = QLineEdit('Tab1')
        LineEdit.setFixedWidth(180)
        vbox.addWidget(Label)
        vbox.addWidget(LineEdit)
        vbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop)
        self.tab_1.setLayout(vbox)

        #tab 2
        self.tab_2 = QWidget()
        self.centralTabs.addTab(self.tab_2,"Label")
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        Label = QLabel('Tab2')
        Label.setFixedWidth(180)
        LineEdit = QLineEdit('Tab2')
        LineEdit.setFixedWidth(180)
        vbox.addWidget(Label)
        vbox.addWidget(LineEdit)
        vbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop)
        self.tab_2.setLayout(vbox)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SurfViewer(app)
    ex.setWindowTitle('window')
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec( ))
```