# Pyqt5 synchronization between two tabwidget which are in different window

Tags: pyqt5

I want to make new window by double click tabwidget.

and copy tabwidget's (child which is tablewidget) to new window.

and finally, changing item of new window's tablewidget needs to change mainwindow's tablewidget.

would it be possible?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48901854/is-it-possible-to-drag-a-qtabwidget-and-open-a-new-window-containing-whats-in-t), that answer does copy tabwidget to new window
but remove mainwindow tabwidget.

here is I worked so far.
I managed to make new dialog by double click, but other things.. I dont' have any clues. can anyone can help?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class DetachableTabWidget(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QTabWidget.__init__(self)
        self.tabBar = self.TabBar(self)
        self.tabBar.onDetachTabSignal.connect(self.detachTab)
        self.setTabBar(self.tabBar)
        print("DetachableTabWidget")

    @pyqtSlot(int, QPoint)
    def detachTab(self, index, point):
        print("detachTab")
        all_list = []
        list1 = []
        list2 = []

        name = self.tabText(index)
        icon = self.tabIcon(index)
        if icon.isNull():
            icon = self.window().windowIcon()
        contentWidget = self.widget(index)
        contentWidgetRect = contentWidget.frameGeometry()

        tablewidgetA = contentWidget.findChild(QTableWidget)
        for i in range(tablewidgetA.rowCount()):
            list1.append(tablewidgetA.item(i, 0).text())
            list2.append(tablewidgetA.item(i, 1).text())

        all_list.append(list1)
        all_list.append(list2)

        detachedTab = self.DetachedTab(all_list)
        detachedTab.setWindowModality(Qt.NonModal)
        detachedTab.setWindowTitle(name)
        detachedTab.setWindowIcon(icon)
        detachedTab.setObjectName(name)
        detachedTab.setGeometry(contentWidgetRect)
        detachedTab.move(point)
        detachedTab.exec_()

    class DetachedTab(QDialog) :
        onCloseSignal = pyqtSignal(QWidget,type(''), QIcon)

        # def __init__(self, contentWidget, parent=None):
        def __init__(self, all_list, parent=None) :
            print("DetachedTab")
            super().__init__()
            layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
            table = QTableWidget()
            table.setColumnCount(len(all_list))
            table.setRowCount(len(all_list[0]))

            for col in range(len(all_list)) :
                for row in range(len(all_list[col])) :
                    item = QTableWidgetItem(all_list[col][row])
                    table.setItem(row, col, item)

            layout.addWidget(table)
            table.show()


    class TabBar(QTabBar):
        onDetachTabSignal = pyqtSignal(int, QPoint)
        onMoveTabSignal = pyqtSignal(int, int)

        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QTabBar.__init__(self, parent)
            self.setAcceptDrops(True)
            self.setElideMode(Qt.ElideRight)
            self.setSelectionBehaviorOnRemove(QTabBar.SelectLeftTab)
            self.dragStartPos = QPoint()
            self.dragDropedPos = QPoint()
            self.mouseCursor = QCursor()
            self.dragInitiated = False

        def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event) :
            event.accept()
            self.onDetachTabSignal.emit(self.tabAt(event.pos()), self.mouseCursor.pos())


class SurfViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SurfViewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.centralTabs = DetachableTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralTabs)
        self.setFixedWidth(600)
        self.setFixedHeight(600)

        #tab 1
        self.tab_1 = QWidget()
        self.centralTabs.addTab(self.tab_1,"Tab 1")
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        Table = QTableWidget(2, 2)
        vbox.addWidget(Table)
        item = QTableWidgetItem("table 1 content")
        Table.setItem( 0, 0, item)
        item = QTableWidgetItem("table 2 content")
        Table.setItem( 0, 1, item)
        item = QTableWidgetItem("table 3 content")
        Table.setItem( 1, 0, item)
        item = QTableWidgetItem("table 4 content")
        Table.setItem( 1, 1, item)
        vbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.tab_1.setLayout(vbox)

        #tab 2
        self.tab_2 = QWidget()
        self.centralTabs.addTab(self.tab_2,"Tab 2")
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        Table = QTableWidget(2, 2)
        item = QTableWidgetItem("table 2 content")
        Table.setItem( 0, 0, item)
        item = QTableWidgetItem("table 3 content")
        Table.setItem( 0, 1, item)
        item = QTableWidgetItem("table 4 content")
        Table.setItem( 1, 0, item)
        item = QTableWidgetItem("table 5 content")
        Table.setItem( 1, 1, item)
        vbox.addWidget(Table)
        vbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.tab_2.setLayout(vbox)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SurfViewer(app)
    ex.setWindowTitle('window')
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_( ))
```

Comment: So, the only thing you're missing is the synchronization between the two tables?

Comment: @musicamante yes, do you have any idea? how to approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to synchronize data between item views, you have to use a common model. Since you're using a QTableWidget (which has an internal, private model, and a higher level item view) you can create a new window using a QTableView instead, and set its model to the source. In that case, you don't need to "copy" row/column/data, you only need to use the source model.

Here's a modified version of your script:

```py
class DetachableTabWidget(QTabWidget):
    # ...
    @pyqtSlot(int, QPoint)
    def detachTab(self, index, point):
        print("detachTab")

        name = self.tabText(index)
        icon = self.tabIcon(index)
        if icon.isNull():
            icon = self.window().windowIcon()
        contentWidget = self.widget(index)
        contentWidgetRect = contentWidget.frameGeometry()

        tablewidgetA = contentWidget.findChild(QTableWidget)

        detachedTab = self.DetachedTab(tablewidgetA.model())
        detachedTab.setWindowTitle(name)
        detachedTab.setWindowIcon(icon)
        detachedTab.setObjectName(name)
        detachedTab.setGeometry(contentWidgetRect)
        detachedTab.move(point)
        detachedTab.exec_()

    class DetachedTab(QDialog) :
        onCloseSignal = pyqtSignal(QWidget,type(''), QIcon)

        def __init__(self, model, parent=None) :
            print("DetachedTab")
            super().__init__()
            layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
            table = QTableView()
            table.setModel(model)

            layout.addWidget(table)
            table.show()
```

With this code you can modify the "child" window table data, and it will always synchronize the source table widget.

Comment: thanks! you solved my problem. I didn't know that there is such way. thank!

Comment: @Shineuichul You're welcome! In any case, sorry for being a bit rude, but, for future reference, please consider being more careful about the title and subject of your questions: in this case your issue is completely unrelated to the matter of "copying" a tab widget. While it might have been the source of your issue, the actual problem was not related to that, and the result was that what you asked was confusing (which is something that would potentially lead people away from your post, even if they were able to help you).